# To implement read file line by line such as readline()

Tags: c, unix, file-read

Like `readline()` function. I thought to implement this,

first I have to read file such as `read(fd, buf, 4096);`, and then, I have to compare `buf[i]` byte by byte like `if (buf[i] == '\n')`.

So, if I find corresponding `i`, then use `lseek()` to go first file offset, and then again `read(fd, buf, i)`. After fisrt operation like this, the second `readline()` call will do this mechanism again.

I thought this solution at first, but comparing `buf[i]`, which means compare byte by byte, is too slow to read all of the character in the `fd`. Must I have to compare like this or is there better solutions??

Comment: why not use fget/fgets?

Comment: It will read line by line. But I want to know solution using read(). Because fgets or any other standard I/O functions eventually use read(), write() system calls.

Comment: Just an idea: You could browse the `readline` source code to see how they do it.

Comment: First, do not worry about the speed of searching for '\n'. Second, use `memchr()` to speed it up.

Comment: @inzanez *why not use fget/fgets?*  They can't handle lines of arbitrary length.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Could you explain with a sample? I don't think I understand what you mean,...:-/

Comment: @inzanez `gets()`/`fgets()` both need to be passed a buffer of fixed length.  If the line is longer than the buffer size, `gets()` will overflow the buffer and `fgets()` will return only the part of the line that fits in the buffer.  [`getline()`, for example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html), will return a line of any length (subject to resource limits such as memory).  For example, reading a 1K line with `char buffer[128]; fgets(buffer,128,fp);` But `char *buf = NULL;size_t bufsize = 0;char *line = getline(&buf, &bufsize, fp):` reads a whole line.

Comment: Many thanks. That makes sense...

Answer (score 3):

I'm supposing that the reason you cannot use `fgets()` is that this is an exercise in which you are supposed to learn something about POSIX low-level I/O functions, and maybe a bit about buffering.  If you really only care about getting the data, then I urge you to wrap a stream around your file descriptor via `fdopen()`, and then to use `fgets()` to read it.

> I thought this solution at first, but comparing buf[i], which means compare byte by byte, is too slow to read all of the character in the fd. Must I have to compare like this or is there better solutions??

You want to read up to the first appearance of a given byte.  How do you suppose you could do that without examining each byte you read?  It's not possible except maybe with hardware support, and you're unlikely to have that.

I think your concern is misplaced, anyway.  It is far more costly to move data from disk to memory than it is to examine the data in memory afterward.  If you're going to work at the low level you propose and you want good performance, then you must read the data from disk in suitably large chunks, as it appears you do in your `read()`-based approach.

On the other hand, it follows that you *also* want to avoid re-reading any data, so if you're after good performance then the `lseek()` is unsuitable.  Moreover, if you need to handle non-seekable files, such as pipes, then `lseek()` is completely out of the question.  In either of those cases, you must maintain the buffer somehow, and be prepared to serve multiple requests from its contents.  Additionally, you must be prepared for the likelihood that line boundaries will not correspond with the buffer boundary, that you may sometimes need more than one read to find a newline, and that it is conceivable that lines will be longer than your buffer, however long that is.

Thus, if `fgets()` and other stream-based I/O alternatives are not an option for you then you have a buffer management problem to solve.  I suggest you start there.  Once you've got that worked out, it should be straightforward to write an analog of `fgets()` in terms of that buffering.

Answer (score -2):

Implement fgetc using a 'read' for 1 character, use your own getc to implement readline?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char my_getc()
{   
    unsigned char ch[1];

    read(1, ch, 1);

    return ch[0];

}

char *my_readline()
{
        char line[4096];
        char *ret;
        char c;
        int position = 0;

        while(c = my_getc() != '\n')
                line[position++] += c;

        line[position] = '\0';

        ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));


        return ret;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char c;

        printf("%s\n", my_readline());

}
```

If you need a well tested solution you should maybe read the source of an existing implementation,...

Comment: 1) The content of `ret[]` is never set - code does not work 2) No protection against buffer overflow, 3) No `EOF` detection. 4) Allocated buffer is not free'd.